# Why are some menu options in Crusader Kings 3 italicized?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

Sometimes menu options are italicized and I'm not sure why. I've seen this happen when you have chance to arrest people as well. What's the meaning of the fancy font decoration?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Menu sub-items are italicized if they are newly added since the last time you opened the the outliner.

Presumably, this is because if "You can declare Wars -- 2" changes to "You can declare Wars -- 3", it's pretty hard for humans to instantly recognized what was added. In this case, look for the italics.

Closing and then opening the tab and/or outliner should remove the italics.